# WP7 - Polygon Textbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, custom-controls

How to create image textbox in WP7?

I do not know enough Expression Blend.![similar to the image]
textbox shape like in the imageImage link:

[image]

Comment: What do u mean by image textbox? Whether is it textbox with image as background?

Comment: textbox shape like in the image..

Comment: What's the editable portion of that textbox? Possibly you could use a `Grid` to build a layout of `Border` objects, one of which contains a `TextBox`. Keep in mind the textbox background color changes depending on whether it has focus. I don't use Blend, I build everything manually in XAML (inefficient, I know) so perhaps someone else could expand on it.